# Unable to Insert Current Timestamp in DB using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have an SQL command in my code behind as:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into MappingInfo(ActivationDate) values (@ActivationDate)", con);
```

I want to assign 'current timestamp' or 'null' to `@ActivationDate`based on some condition, as shown below:

```
int ActivateState;
if (rdoActivateMappingYes.Checked)
{
    ActivateState = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationDate", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
}
else
{
    ActivateState = 0;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationDate", DBNull.Value);
}
```

However, upon running the web app, I am getting the following error:

```
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException} : {"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."}
```

Comment: `"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` is a `string`, not a `DateTime` or something. How about using your local time as `DateTime.Now` or your UTC time (_as a better way of course_) as `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: @SonerGönül I understood that! Can you please tell me how to enter the current timestamp? What is the correct approach?

Comment: You would be better served if you defined your datatypes for your parameters instead of forcing the system to figure it out. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int ActivateState;
if (rdoActivateMappingYes.Checked)
{
    ActivateState = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationDate", DateTime.Now);
}
else
{
    ActivateState = 0;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationDate", DBNull.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The message is clear.

The field ActivationDate is a DateTime field, but you are passing a string as value: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Probably you will have to pass a DateTime value, as DateTime.Now, or any other DateTime that suits the logic of your app/database.

Comment: I understood that! Can you please tell me how to enter the current timestamp? What is the correct approach?

Comment: @AniruddhaPondhe, use DateTime.Now, or DateTime.UtcNow (mentioned by rodrigoqg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datetime.parse() method to check if the string is in valid date format.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900");
```